# Ionic 3 - how use cordova plugin Network interface with ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

**My problem:** 
I need my app to search the local WiFi network to find a server computer with a application on a specific port. I don't want to hard code the server IP address into the app as it could be possibly used in many locations.

**Update:** So I need to be able to find the IP address of all devices on the network.

**What iv done so far:**

Iv followed other guides on stack overflow and online by doing the following steps:

**1. install cordova plugin:**

```
 "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface"
```

**2. Declare the variable in global scope to access the object**

```
declare var NetworkInterface: any;
export class TestClass{}
```

**3. Call the object using the global variable inside a component**

```
NetworkInterface.getWiFiIPAddress((ip) => {
   console.log("network ip address = " + ip);
});
```

However this causes an error on run time when running from the mobile:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):  ReferenceError: NetworkInterface
>   is not defined

I've also tried declaring a variable globally and then trying to apply a string value in a component, only to get the same problem. It appears to be more of a problem with the variable not working globally? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use below `CLI`:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface --save
```

You need to declare it as global.And also you need to test this on either `device` or `emulator` since this is a `plugin`.

```
 declare var NetworkInterface: any;
```

**Old Answer:**

You can easily do it using native [**Network**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

From the doc:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

constructor(private network: Network) { }

...

// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
   // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
      console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of the native network plugin, but it does not provided a list of IP address of devices on the local network. It only informs you if you are connected to a WiFi. I need to test IP address on network to find the server/application. Thanks though.

Comment: As iv stated in my original post, I'm already testing on my mobile device and  Iv declared the variable outside of the class as suggested in other guides, but still having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks Sampath, your solution also works! The only modification I had to use was adding cordova for ionic 3; `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface --save`

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue by accessing the window object directly and then the networkinterface object.

**Code Solution:**

```
 (<any>window).networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress((ip) => {
     console.log("network ip address = " + ip);
 });
```

This means I no longer have to use a global variable for reference. Hopefully this will help someone else.

**Update thanks to Sampath for another solution; It appears I should of used:**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface --save
```

**Instead of:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

Comment: Why would you want to bypass the entire angular ecosystem?

Comment: Hey niroice, this is awesome thanks for sharing your solution! I'm trying to do a similar thing where I need to find the IP address of all devices on my network. Any change you could share how you did that once you have your network IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the Network plugin you just need to add it to your app.module.ts providers collection. This registers it as a singleton.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Network
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you can simply import and and use it on a page as per the [plugin docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/).

Comment: I'm not using the native ionic plugin. I'm using a "non-native" network interface plugin.

Comment: Sorry, then you need to reference the NetworkInterface plugin in providers.